# requireJS pass configuration info to all modules with "*" wildcard

Tags: javascript, configuration, requirejs, amd

I have a need to pass a configuration value into all my AMD modules using requireJS.

I can happily pass a configuration value to a specific module by using the following example; as given in the [requireJS API config modules](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-moduleconfig) documentation

```
requirejs.config({
    config: {
        'bar': {
            raw: true
        },
        'baz': {
            raw: true
        },
        ...
    }
});
```

The above works fine, but I have some 50 modules that I want to pass the same configuration value to, and these could increase or change. I could define 50 module names, as above, and pass the value, but I don't really want to have to define each module by name and maintain that list, instead I'd like to do something like this.

```
requirejs.config({
    config: {
        '*': {
            raw: true
        }
    }
});
```

I have tried the above but it did not work.

[requireJS config map](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map) appears to support the "*" wildcard, but I don't see any mention of similar for "config". I have searched, but I guess I'm having a "bad search day".

So, the question is: Is there a "*" wildcard support for "config" and I am just having a problem with it? Or is there some other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know a way to use the wildcard syntax directly, but you can accomplish the same thing through the [simplest](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defsimple) module definition at the bottom of your data-main:

```
requirejs.config({
    // normal stuff
});

define('moduleconfig', {
    color: "black",
    size: "unisize"
});
```

And then instead of requiring the special 'module' module, just require your 'moduleconfig' module:

```
define( ['underscore', 'jquery', 'moduleconfig'], function( _, $, moduleconfig) {

    console.log('Color', moduleconfig.color)

 });
```

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed appear to work. I created a default "moduleconfig" for the case where I want defaults and then I can override it by redefining it in my main. It still seems strange that there is (apparently) no wildcard support for module config, I did take a quick look through the requireJS source but didn't notice any such thing.

Comment: So, I guess if there had been a wildcard method, someone would have jumped in with an answer by now. Thanks once again for the help.